# does the pricing for s3 data transfer out of the internet includes for reading file contents

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-transfer

I have a web app with a download buttons to download objects from s3 buckets. I also have plot buttons to read the contents of csv files in s3 bucket using pandas read_csv to read the columns and make visualizations. I wanted to understand if the price for s3 data transfer out of the internet is only for actually download of files or it also includes just reading the contents too because the bytes are transferred over the internet in that case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 does not operate like a file system. There is no notion of reading and writing portions of files as you would to a local or remote drive. To read a file you must always download the entire file and then read portions as needed. That is why AWS only shows pricing for data transfer.

Comment: Technically, it is possible to do random seeks and reads, using `Range` requests, and in those cases only the actual bytes transferred would be billable... but that is a limited circumstance, and the gist of this answer is correct -- **"downloading" is exactly the same thing as "reading bytes from"** an object in S3.  Unless the file is being read from EC2, in which case the per-GB cost is eliminated (same region) or reduced (cross-region).

Comment: Great detail to point out. The simplicity of my answer hopefully matched that of the question. Technical details on range requests can be found in the [GET Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) documentation.